# Eclipse Mars - The currently displayed page contains invalid values

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-mars

I'm using Eclipse and was experimenting with WebDriver, DBunit, Maven and the likes.  One fine moment I needed to add a Reference Library (right click project > Properties > Java Build Path), and I'm suddenly getting the error "The currently displayed page contains invalid values." :(

Any ideas? I've already re-installed Eclipse and re-instated my workspace but the problem occurred again.

Comment: There is usually a message in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for this.

Comment: Yes there is thanks! Still clueless what it refers to though.  I'm getting this error "!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.preferences.BuildPathsPropertyPage.noDefaultButton()V"

Comment: Possibly a mismatch between plugins versions you have installed. Eclipse Mars is still under development and is only available in pre-release Milestone builds. It may be that something you have installed is not compatible with Mars.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Mars is still under development. I'd recommend you use their last stable release, Eclipse Luna, instead of using the Eclipse version in development.

Comment: I was getting same problem and I took latest update. Its worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments Mars is under development and dates for release on 24th June 2015.  I had no idea and haven't had issues in the past 3 months working on small stuff.  To answer my own question though, all I did to solve the issue was go to "Help > Check for Updates" and this seems to have solved this specific issue for the time being.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Installing the updates in Eclipse Mars fixed the issue for me.